# Not able to get entire text of current buffer in vim

Tags: function, vim, buffer

I am trying to get entire text of current buffer. I believe it is represented by '%' (see answer by SnoringFrog at https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2319/is-there-a-text-object-for-the-entire-buffer). However, following function gives an error:

```
function Check ()
   echo %
endfunction
```

I call it with following command:

```
:call Check()
```

The error is:

```
Error detected while processing function Check:
line    1:
E15: Invalid expression: %
E15: Invalid expression: %
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the context, `%` can be a shortcut for the `1,$` range or a placeholder for the filename associated with the current buffer.

In the first case (the one in your link), it's not meant to be echoed at all which would be completely pointless.

In the second case, it needs to be expanded with `expand('%')` if you want to use it in a function.

Anyway, none of that matters because `%` is not what you want *at all*. What you want is `:help getline()`:

```
function Check ()
    echo getline(1,'$')
endfunction
```

Comment: Yes, it works. But blank lines are being ignored. Any way to include them as well in the list obtained from getline function.

Comment: No, blank lines are not ignored.